# java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject error

Tags: java, json

I had been trying to fix this for days and still no luck. I am new in this.

Here is my JSONParser:

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);          
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

This is the error log:

```
02-13 11:43:34.439: E/JSON(948):         <script type="text/javascript">
02-13 11:43:34.439: E/JSON(948):             <!--
02-13 11:43:34.439: E/JSON(948):             window.location = "http://p.pw/404"
02-13 11:43:34.439: E/JSON(948):             //-->
02-13 11:43:34.439: E/JSON(948):         </script>
02-13 11:43:34.439: E/JSON(948):     
02-13 11:43:34.439: E/JSON Parser(948): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value     <script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Is the output of json suppose to be a script in the first place? If no, then what is it suppose to output?

Comment: did you check the json,it  is valid ?

Comment: erm... how to check it? xD

Comment: The uri your code is retrieving is not JSON

Comment: @firaga that is not a json that is a javascript code.

Comment: it's not javascript, it's html